# How to not show specific URLs in search webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

I would like to list all the sites from an URL that I have, all excepts a few, how can I change the question? Now my questions is:

```
contentclass:STS_site 
Path:HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites*
```

and that gives me all sites , but I want to exclude specific URL's, what do I write?

I tried:

```
(contentclass:STS_site != Path:HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testproject && Path:HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites*)
```

but it did not work.. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the keyword `NOT` instead of `!=` and `AND` instead if `&&`

In this case I think you should use `OR` between the excludes instead of `AND`

Something like

```
contentclass:STS_site NOT (path:HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testproject OR path:HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites*)
```

although the above would just exclude everythinh below `HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites*` (if this is not just an example)

Answer (score 1):

**NOT instead of !=**

```
contentclass:STS_Site NOT Site:HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testproject NOT Site:HTTPS://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites*
```